# Absolute and conditional convergence of a series with $\cos$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \cos^2(2n)}{\sqrt{n}}$$

In case of conditional convergence, I suppose series is convergent (Dirichlet's test). But I don't know how to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{m} \cos^2(2n)$ is bounded.
In case of absolute convergence I don't have good idea.
Could you give me any tips?

Comment: How the plan of letting us doing all your homeworks is going on?

Comment: Tip: $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n\cdot\frac{1}{2}}{\sqrt{n}}$ is clearly convergent, and $\frac{1}{2}-\cos^2(2n)$ can be developped as a Fourier cosine series. By Dirichlet's test, $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n \cos(mn)}{\sqrt{n}}$$ is convergent for every $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: By similar reasons (summation by parts), the original series **is not** absolutely convergent, $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\cos^2(2n)}{\sqrt{n}}\approx\sqrt{N}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Dirichlet's Test, you need to prove that
\begin{align}
\sum^N_{n=1} (-1)^n\cos^2(2n)
\end{align}
is bounded. Observe
\begin{align}
\sum^{N}_{n=1} (-1)^n\cos^2(2n) =&\ \sum^N_{n=1}(-1)^n\left(\frac{1+\cos(4n)}{2} \right) \\
=&\ \sum^N_{n=1}(-1)^n\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Re}\sum^N_{n=1} (-1)^ne^{i4n}\\
=&\ \sum^N_{n=1}(-1)^n\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Re} \frac{-e^{i4}-(-1)^{N+1}e^{i4(N+1)}}{1+e^{i4}}
\end{align}
which is bounded since
\begin{align}
\sum^N_{n=1}(-1)^n\frac{1}{2} =
\begin{cases}
-\frac{1}{2} & \text{ if } N \text{ is odd}\\
0 &\ \text{ if } N \text{ is even}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\left|\frac{e^{i4}+(-1)^{N+1}e^{i4(N+1)}}{1+e^{i4}} \right|< \frac{1}{|\cos 2|}.
\end{align}

For the absolute convergence part note that we are considering the series
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1+\cos(4n)}{2\sqrt{n}}.
\end{align}

Again applying Dirichlet's Test, we see that
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{\cos(4n)}{2\sqrt{n}}<\infty
\end{align} 
which means
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1} \frac{1+\cos(4n)}{2\sqrt{n}} = \infty.
\end{align}

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife You are right. I have made the correction.

Answer (score 0):

One way to see $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos^2(2n)/\sqrt n = \infty$ is to notice that $\cos^2(2x) + \cos^2(2(x+1))$ is periodic (with period $\pi/2$) and is never $0.$ It follows that there is $c>0$ such that $\cos^2(2x) + \cos^2(2(x+1)) > c$ for all $x.$ Thus for all $n,$

$$\frac{\cos^2(2n)}{\sqrt n} + \frac{\cos^2(2(n+1))}{\sqrt {n+1}} \ge \frac{\cos^2(2n)}{\sqrt {n+1}} + \frac{\cos^2(2(n+1))}{\sqrt {n+1}}> \frac{c}{\sqrt {n+1}}.$$

Since $\sum c/\sqrt {n+1} = \infty,$ we have shown divergence.